# Javascript File path fix

Tags: javascript

How do i convert the string;

```
var s='uploads\product\picture\20Duleek_Lime_Green1.jpg';
```

into

```
'uploads/product/picture/20Duleek_Lime_Green1.jpg';
```

The standard javascript function replace doesnt seem to work.

```
var s='uploads\product\picture\20Duleek_Lime_Green1.jpg';

strReplace = s.replace('\\', '//');

alert(strReplace);
```

Comment: Use .replace(), not .replaceAll()

Comment: @ianpgall, well that is partially right, if you did that, it would only replace the first instance.

Comment: sorry i ment "replace" and not replaceAll was using that to test another function.

Comment: @epascarello crap, i guess i'm mixing up .replace() methods between languages. sorry, you're right!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no replaceAll in JavaScript, use a regular expression with a global flag.

```
var s='uploads\\product\\picture\\20Duleek_Lime_Green1.jpg';
var strReplace = s.replace(/\\/g, '/');
alert(strReplace);
```

Answer (score 0):

There is **no such function** in javascript called `replaceAll`

You can use `regex` with `replace()` to achieve what you want to do.